# Create in-Application questions-tests with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, testing

i am a developer and i am searching about in-Application tests development. What is in-Application tests?

Let me give you an example:

The application is launched and fires up the Microsoft Word for example. Opens a document file and ask from the students to select and bold the first paragraph. The students carry out activities within the live application itself and they finally click the button "Check my answer". The application has to automatically judge whether they have achieved the required outcome.

A better explanation may be here: http://www.enlightks.com/ecdlicdl-solution/home/application-testing

I cannot find anything similar in web about developing this kind of application. Can someone quide me or helping me find a "way" or giving me some resources to start with ?

(As i said before, i am a programmer but my previous experience hasn't any relationship to this kind of development)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could to ask users to save their work with  predefined file name. Later, you could to open that document with OpenXML and check if that format is expressed inside that document.

In this case, you student just can check for answers when he/she finishes all tasks.

Another way could be to build an Office addin, which would to place a button to check his/her answer. I think this could be a more interactive version, but you'll have more work to do.

Comment: The way that the systems work is more close to the second one. But the don't use an Office addin, the check and the control is all done by the main application which controls the Live Application (Word, Excel, etc.)
My indentions are to extend this in other applications like Photoshop, Corel creating in-Application tests